# Float can't go over 256?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm making a game, in which I am setting a location with a float, the problem is the float isn't going higher them 255?
This is how I'm making the float go higher:
1. add method:

```
public Location add(float x, float y, float z){
    this.x += x; this.y += y; this.z += z;
    return this;
}
```

2. update method

```
public void update(){
        float speed = 0.00001f;
        float rotspeed = 0.00001f;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) Main.renderer.rotate(-rotspeed, 0, 0);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) Main.renderer.rotate(rotspeed, 0, 0);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) Main.renderer.rotate(0, rotspeed, 0);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) Main.renderer.rotate(0, -rotspeed, 0);

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) Main.renderer.renderLocation.add(0, 0, speed);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) Main.renderer.renderLocation.add(0, 0, -speed);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) Main.renderer.renderLocation.add(-speed, 0, 0);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) Main.renderer.renderLocation.add(speed, 0, 0);

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) Main.renderer.renderLocation.add(0, -speed, 0);
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT)) Main.renderer.renderLocation.add(0, speed, 0);
        fixRenderRotation();
    }
```

The update is being called in a while loop in a child thread.

This is what I'm using the float for

```
public void update(){
    System.out.println("render_location "+renderLocation.x+" "+renderLocation.y+" "+renderLocation.z+" rotation "+rotation.x+" "+rotation.y+" "+rotation.z);
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glTranslatef(renderLocation.x, renderLocation.y, renderLocation.z);
    //GL11.glTranslatef(renderLocation.x, renderLocation.y, renderLocation.z);
    GL11.glRotatef(rotation.x, 1F, 0F, 0F);
    GL11.glRotatef(rotation.y, 0F, 1F, 0F);
    GL11.glRotatef(rotation.z, 0F, 0F, 1F);
    ((RenderObject.UnknownRenderInformation) collection.getRenderInformation()).act();
}
```

It's the `renderLocaiton` variable.
I am not stopping it from going higher.

Comment: *Something* is, and that something is not the internal representation of floats.

Comment: @DaveNewton are you sure?  I would wonder if a `float` was precise enough to represent `255.00001f` as distinct from `255f`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sure, but that's not what the question asks--OP is saying it won't go over 256. Or 255, depending on which sentence you read.

Comment: Well, yes, that would be a side effect if `256.00001f == 256f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` only has ~6 digits of accuracy. I suggest using an `int` and dividing by 100,000 or using a `double`

When you add `1e-5f` to `256f` the answer is `256f` as this is closest represent-able value. You have the same problem with double but at a much higher point. If you add `1e-5` to `137438953472` the same thing will happen as you are working beyond the precision of a `double`.

If you use an int you will a different problem. Add `1` to `2147483647` and the `int` will overflow to `-2147483648`

BTW You have a problem with float before you reach 256.  Due to representation error `128f + 1e-5f == 128.00002` which I suspect is not what you intended.

In fact if you keep adding 1e-5f it will only takes 65536 times to increment between integer value/whole numbers instead of the 100,000 you might have expected.

It is useful to know the limits of your types.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the Peter's answer, this is a compulsory read: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

What happens is basically 256.00001f gets rounded down to 256f (255.00001f, on the other side, is rounded up to 255.00002f). You can store 256.00002f, but it will get rounded up to 256.00003f. First rounding *down* happens at 256.00001f and that's where you hit the limit, so any other 0.00001 addition will have no effect (every time you add it, it will be discarded due to rounding). As you might have noticed, because of the way exponent and mantissa work fifth decimal of a float isn't particularly reliable, so if you want better precision, use doubles, but don't expect perfect accuracy from them either.